# HTTP response header, format for "Expires"

Tags: c#, http-headers

I am setting this in C# with this line:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add(HttpResponseHeader.Expires, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10).ToString());
```

Now I know the format is off on this as it expects the following: Tue, 06 Dec 2011 20:24:15 GMT

Is there a class in .NET implementing `IFormatProvider` I could leverage here?  Or will I need to create my own?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.90).aspx).

> Tue, 06 Dec 2011 20:24:15 GMT

generate the above format like so:

```cs
DateTime.Now.AddDays(30).ToUniversalTime()
    .ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'");
```

Comment: Beware, this code is not culture insensitive and will format the date using the server locale. You should either use `thedate.ToString("R")` or `thedate.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)`

Comment: As suggested by Steve B and in Jonno's [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17079611/361762), format string "R" is the best way to do this. e.g. `DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30).ToString("R")`

Comment: @SteveB you'r advice worth more than an answer. tnx so much.

Answer (score 38):

I use `DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30).ToString("R")`

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#RFC1123):

> The "R" or "r" standard format specifier represents a custom date and time format string that is defined by the [DateTimeFormatInfo.RFC1123Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.rfc1123pattern.aspx) property. The pattern reflects a defined standard, and the property is read-only. Therefore, it is always the same, regardless of the culture used or the format provider supplied. The custom format string is "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'". When this standard format specifier is used, the formatting or parsing operation always uses the invariant culture

Comment: When the current culture is not "en, you'll produce invalid dates and sometimes include invalid non-ascii characters in the HTTP header, use `DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30).ToString("R", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass string and set Header. All you need, is to set LastModified property:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.LastModified = DateTime.Now; // DataTime.UtcNow;
```

You don't even need to wory about passing UTC time, it handles it for you.

Answer (score -8):

I ended up creating this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WcfService1
{
    public static class HttpExpiresFormat
    {

        private enum Month
        {
            Jan = 1, Feb = 2, Mar = 3, Apr = 4, May = 5, Jun = 6, Jul = 7, Aug = 8, Sept = 9, Oct = 10, Nov = 11, Dec = 12
        }


        public static string HttpExpireDate(double secondsToAdd)
        {
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

            string dayOfWeek = ConvertDayToSmall(dateTime.DayOfWeek.ToString());
            string day = dateTime.Day < 10 ? "0" + dateTime.Day.ToString() : dateTime.Day.ToString();
            string month = ((Month)dateTime.Month).ToString();
            string year = dateTime.Year.ToString();
            char[] trim = new char[] { '.' };
            string substring = dateTime.AddHours(5).AddSeconds(secondsToAdd).TimeOfDay.ToString();
            string time = substring.Remove(substring.LastIndexOf('.')) + " GMT";

            return string.Format("{0}, {1} {2} {3} {4}", dayOfWeek, day, month, year, time);
        }

        private static string ConvertDayToSmall(string day)
        {
            switch (day)
            {
                case "Monday":
                    return "Mon";
                case "Tuesday":
                    return "Tue";
                case "Wednesday":
                    return "Wed";
                case "Thursday":
                    return "Thu";
                case "Friday":
                    return "Fri";
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Likely breaks for machines set to locales other than en-us.